# How to find the outliers of a Ruby array/hash of integers?

Tags: ruby, math, statistics, boxplot, outliers

Here is my input:

```
[{name: 'John', age: 50}, {name: 'Bob', age: 50}, {name: 'Paul', age: 0}, {name: 'Alfred', age: 100}]
```

I want to find the extreme ages, and I want to be able to put in as a variable how sensible the extremes should be. So, for example I would put in that I want to find the 10% most extreme values. So e.g. the output would be something like this:

```
# the extreme min values => [{name: 'Paul', age: 0}]
# the extreme max values => [{name: 'Alfred', age: 100}]
```

How do I do that?

I found some resources online that might help, but honestly I'm not able to follow the examples myself:

http://sciruby.com/blog/2013/11/07/statistics-with-ruby-time-series-and-general-linear-models/
http://statsample.apsique.cl/Statsample/Graph/Boxplot.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way.

1.Sort the list:

```
a = [{name: 'John', age: 50}, {name: 'Bob', age: 50}, {name: 'Paul', age: 0}, {name: 'Alfred', age: 100}]
a = a.sort{|a,b| a['age'] <=> b['age']}
```

2.the first element is now the minimum, the last is the maximum.

```
min, max  = a[0], a[-1]
```

Note that this is likely not the most efficient way to do this, but for small arrays it is good enough.

Wrt your sensitivities, the above method works by multiplying the length of the array L by the percentage p yielding l, then dividing by two, and taking elements

```
[0..l-1]
```

as your lower outliers and

```
[L-(l-1), L-1]
```

as your upper outliers

Edit: worked example

`L` is the length of the array, `p` is the ratio of outliers that you want.

```
l = (L*p)/2
```

For `p=0.2, L=20` we'd want the four outliers, two on the minimum and two on the maximum side.

```
l = (L*p)/2 = 2

min = a[0..1]
max = a[(L-(l-1), L-1] = a[(20-(2-1), 19] = a[19,19]
```

Note that this indicates there's an error in what I told you above - max should probably be `a[(L-l),(L-1)]` instead.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. Could you add an example of e.g. `[L-(l-1), L-1]`?

Comment: @ChristofferJoergensen see above for a worked example.

Answer (score 0):

The starting point for this is the [`minmax`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-minmax) method:

```
min_val, max_val = [1, 3, 0, 9, 6].minmax # => [0, 9]
```

If you need to dig into an object to figure out its value, use [`minmax_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-minmax_by):

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :i
  def initialize(i)
    @i = i
  end
end

min_foo, max_foo = [1, 3, 0, 9, 6].map{ |n| Foo.new(n) }.minmax_by{ |foo| foo.i }
# => [#<Foo:0x007fd6dc8630c0 @i=0>, #<Foo:0x007fd6dc863098 @i=9>]
```

Comment: But this only return 2 objects, the lowest and the highest, right? I ned to find the extreme e.g. 10%.

Comment: Right. It's the basis for doing what you need, it's not meant to be an entire answer. You can build up on this.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `arr` is your array of hashes. You want to find the `n` values of that array for which `arr[i][:age]` are largest. You could do that by sorting on `arr[i][:age]` and then taking the last `n` elements.  If, however, `n` is a small fraction of `arr.size`, it may be faster to find and save the one for which `arr[i][:age]` is largest, remove it and repeat `n-1` times.

**Code**

```
def top_n(arr, n)
  ad = arr.dup
  n.times.with_object([]) do |_,a|
    j = ad.each_index.max_by { |i| ad[i][:age] }
    a << ad[j]
    ad.delete_at(j)
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
arr = [{name: 'John'  , age:  50},
       {name: 'Bob'   , age:  50},
       {name: 'Tina'  , age:  80},
       {name: 'Paul'  , age:   0},
       {name: 'Alfred', age: 100}]

top_n(arr, 3)
  #=> [{:name=>"Alfred", :age=>100},
  #    {:name=>"Tina",   :age=>80},
  #    {:name=>"John",   :age=>50}]
```